# Laravel - 2 queries over nothing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Hello guys,

in the [official doc of Eloquent for Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-updates), this is the way to make an update to a table :

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);
$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';
$flight->save();
```

I must say, I don't really understand that. For me, it means that for a very basic update, there will be 2 queries to the database - a select and THEN an update ?

Anyone could explain me why this would be a good solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any abstraction is used for complex applications. The code is too simple that you can not feel it advantage. The Object Relation Mapping (ORM) is used to hide details of operating databases, or running SQL queries.

Just like the MVC model, different layers are in charge of different fields.

View: render HTML

Controller: Logical control, like `if .. else ..`

Model: data access, like data modification and persistence.

The controller layer won't take care of how model layer works, you just find a object like `$flight`, and change its property, and `save()`. That is natural and neat. Your controller layer are all about Object modifying, instead of data modifying.

By separating data and object, you can easily, or at lease possibly, change the implementation of data persistence.

If some objects are frequently changed, you can save it on `Redis` or `Memcached` or other `NoSQL` storage. The controller layer's code needs no change.

If some objects are very large and not modify quite often, you can consider using some distributed storage, or using `lazy loading` techniques. Your controller code also unchanged. You just change the model layer's implementation, the upper codes will not aware of the change.

Decoupling or layering codes, makes it easy to change any layer's implementation. If you think wring two lines of SQL queries is quicker than ORM, maybe you need to experience larger projects with highly demand changing and performance optimization.

It is always good that separating the implementation and the usage.

Edit:

You can use `where` and `update` to update by id. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-updates

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)
          ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
          ->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. Actually, separation of concerns is very clear to me - beginning with laravel, I'm not beginning with programming though - nor mvc patterns. I understand the point. For more complex queries - sure, it makes perfect sense. But still, for very simple queries, it's still 1 unneeded select. And that type of simple queries appears in every application, here and there. Shouldn't there be a simple way to update the data through the orm without doing that unneeded query ? I feel it less needed after reading your response, but still it bothers me.

Comment: I finally find that you can use the `active record` to avoid the selection.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo  `App\Flight::where('id', 1)->update(['name' => 'New Flight Name'])`.

Answer (score 1):

There is some benefit of using this approach if you want to ensure that you're modifying only one valid record.

On the other hand there is another way in the documentation:

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)
          ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
          ->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

It's your preference whether you need to ensure the single record modification or not.